# Pool Testing Given Infection Rate

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

**Edit:** A problem from an ongoing math competition

Suppose you have a group of 10,000 people where about 5% of them are infected. You have a testing pool machine which can pool up to 32 samples and tell you if one or more people are infected, or none are infected. What is the best strategy to figure out who has the infection that requires the fewest tests, on average.

I've seen similar questions, but in all of them, after identifying the positive group, they then test everyone individually, which seems like an incredible waste of the 32 person pooling machine, especially given the infection rate is relatively low.

Comment: @hardmath The goal is to identify who has the infection using the minimal number of tests.

Comment: @hardmath I did. Any hints?

Comment: This is problem #5 from the [2021 Mathcamp qualifying quiz](https://www.mathcamp.org/qualifying_quiz/current_quiz/), for which the deadline is March 18th. Posting it here is against the MSE contest problem policy, and also against the rules for the qualifying quiz.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Thanks for pointing that out.  I've deleted my Comment and flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it violates the site policy on ongoing math contests.